# LINQ - Get minimum count between 2 opposing criteria

Tags: c#, linq

I don't know how to phrase the title to this question, but suppose I have the following 2 variables defined in my C# program:

```
var maxVal = 8;
var myList = new List<int> { 1, 4, 6, 7, 1, 2, 6, 3, 8};
```

And suppose I want to get the minimum between:

```
a) The number of elements with values < maxVal / 2
b) The number of elements with values >= maxVal / 2
```

So, given the example values above, we would have:

```
a) {1,1,2,3} => count = 4
b) {4,6,7,6,8} => count = 5
```

So I would want the value of 4.

The way I can come up with for doing this is:

```
var output = Math.Min(
    myList.Where(v => v < maxVal / 2).Count(),
    myList.Where(v => v >= maxVal / 2).Count()
    );
```

But I'm curious to know if the Linq library allows for a way (maybe using grouping or something)

Thanks!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well you can make it work using ToLookup or GroupBy

```
myList.ToLookup(v => v < maxVal / 2).Min(grp => grp.Count())
myList.GroupBy(v => v < maxVal / 2).Min(grp => grp.Count())
```

This assumes that there are only two possible groups

- values lesser than half the max
- all others (equal or greater)

If you have more than 2 groups you need to create a more complex function that selects a key for grouping

```
myList.GroupBy(v => _getKey(v, maxValue)).Min(grp => grp.Count())
...
private int _getKey(int value, int maxValue )
{
    if(value < maxValue / 4) return 0;
    if(value < maxValue / 2) return 1;
    if(value < maxValue / 4 * 3) return 2;
    return 3;
}
```

See [here](https://dotnetfiddle.net/1oc0Eh)

For the record, using Count you can also specify a predicate

```
  myList.Count(v => v < maxVal / 2),
```

Comment: HOLY WOW THAT IS AWESOME!!!!! - That is a REALLY cool trick that makes perfect sense!!!

Comment: As for your addition with the count with the predicate, I did think of that, but couldn't think of how to make it work for the minimum between the 2.